# How to read folder names and put them into a table list using lua

Tags: lua

I have a folder with a list of folders (organisation>> customer numbers). Is there a way to read the folder names(customer numbers) and put them in a table using lua?

The folder is located at path: c:\user\organisation; under organisation the subfolders are the customer folders labelled by their ids. I would like to read the ids and put them on a table for comparing with another list

Please advice.

Comment: I use `path` library like `t = {}; path.each('*.*', function(n) table.insert(t,n) end, {skipfiles=true, skipdirs=false})`

Comment: Thank You moteus for your advice. took your advice and added to what I knew... I was able to solve my question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the folder names using the following code

```
a = {}
for dir in io.popen([[dir "C:\Users\" /b /ad]]):lines() do table.insert(a, dir) end
   print(table.getn(a))
```